# Android studio won't let me use switch on a string?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, switch-statement

I'm creating a android app in android studio and trying to create a switch case on a string. As far as i know this is possible, as long as you got a JDK equals to 7 or higher. I'm using the following `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home` and still gets an error when trying to switch on a string.

Anyone knows why it still fails, any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I get this eroor `Error:(15, 16) error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)` so clearly somewhere in my project it uses JDK 1.6 but i can't figure out where.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Error:(15, 16) error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)

Comment: do not use jre higher than 1.6 or java 6. since android runtime has java 6.If you use java 7 or java 8 at compile time than you get exception when running app in emulator or device.

Comment: It runs just fine on my device though:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you will have to add this to your build.gradle ( into the android section )

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Comment: Results in this: Error:(11, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compileOptions()'!

Comment: it needs to go in the android section - have a look here: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks that worked. My project is now running just fine on my device

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project "Properties" then Java Compiler , check the "enable project specific settings"

you will get the compiler compliance settings change it to 1.7 and you will be able to use strings in switch